# Can't prove equation

Tags: functions

Recently I have been working on an algorithm and haven't been completely able to continue because I've been stuck trying to create the formula of this curve. The curve has the following points: $(x,y), ((x+y),(y+1)), ((x+2y +1), (y+2)), ((x+3y+3), (y+3))$, etc. So far I have been able to also find that $y^2 = 2x + y$. **Basically the $y$ coordinates increase by 1 everytime and $x$ increases by the previous y**. The problem is I haven't been able to completely solve for $y$ and I am not sure if quadratic formula will work here. How do I solve the equation for this curve?

Comment: Are you trying to find the equation of that line?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit post to make it clearer

Comment: Do you have any fixed starting point corresponding to your $(x,y)$?

Comment: Initial x is 0, y is 1

Comment: You need some subscripts. ($x_{n+1}, y_{n+1})$ = ($x_n$+$y_{n-1}$, $y_n$ + 1), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your points can be defined by the recurrence relation $y_n = y + n$ and $x_n = x_{n-1} + y_{n-1}$ with $x_0 = a$ and $y_0 = b$ begin the initial values. We will first try to write parametric equations in terms of $n$. It is clear that $y_n = b + n$. Now we will work on the $x$ coordinate
\begin{align}
x_n &= x_{n-1} + y_{n - 1}\\
&= x_{n - 1} + b + n - 1\\
&= (x_{n-2} + b + n - 2) + b + n - 1\\
&= x_{n - 2} + 2b + (n-2) + (n - 1)\\
&\vdots \\
&=x_{n-n} + bn + 1 + 2 + \cdots + (n - 2) + (n-1)\\
&= a + bn + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
&= \frac{n^2 + (2b - 1)n + 2a}{2}
\end{align}
We know have the parametric equations of the curve.
Recall that $y_n = b + n$ so $n = y_n - b$
\begin{align}
(y_n - b)^2 + (2b - 1)(y_n - b) + 2a &= 2x_n\\
(y_n - b)^2 + (2b - 1)(y_n - b) + (2a - 2x_n) &= 0
\end{align}
then by the quadratic formula(we use the positive root if $a,b>0$)
\begin{align}
y_n - b = \frac{1 - 2b + \sqrt{(2b-1)^2  - 8(a - x_n)}}{2}\\
y_n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{(2b - 1)^2 - 8(a - x_n)}}{2}
\end{align}
Therefore the function for $a = 0, b = 1$ would be
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 8x}}{2}
\end{equation}
Note that the equation may not work depending on the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the coordinates: (0,1),(1,2),(3,3),(6,4) ...   The x coordinate is equal to the sum of numbers from 0 to y-1 which is $\sum_{i=1}^y(i-1)$ Using 1+2+..+n = (n+1)*n/2,

You can generalize the coordinates as ((n*(n+1)/2),(n+1)).From here,
n+1 = y
x  = (n*(n+1)/2) = (y-1)*y/2
2x = y$^2$-y

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(y)$ be a function, and $x=f(y)$. From the given information,
$$f(1) = 0,\quad f(y) =f(y-1)+(y-1)$$

Solving the recursion, for $y\in\mathbb N$,
$$\begin{align*}
f(y) &= f(y-1)+(y-1)\\
&= f(y-2)+(y-2)+(y-1)\\
&\vdots\\
&= f(y-k)+\sum_{i=1}^k(y-i)&&k\in\mathbb N\\
&= f(y-k) + ky-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\\
&= f(0)+y^2-\frac{y(y+1)}2&&k=y\\
&= \frac{y^2-y}{2}\\
2f(y) &= y^2-y\\
2x &= y^2-y
\end{align*}$$
Verify that, by replacing $y$ with $y+1$,
$$(y+1)^2-(y+1) = y^2+2y+1-y-1 = 2(f(y)+y)$$
So the equation does in fact work for fractional or negative $y$.